# Listview search result onclick wrong return

Tags: java, android

When I click list item from search result, return to 0 position. How do I get original position from string?

My code is:

String.xml

```
<resources>
        <string name="app_name">SearchViewList</string>
        <string-array name="array_country">
            <item>Alemania</item>
            <item>Mexico</item>
            <item>EUA</item>
            <item>Argentina</item>
            <item>Rusia</item>
            <item>España</item>
        </string-array>
</resources>
```

My code is:

MenuSearch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
            android:title="Buscar"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

My code is:
MainActivity.java

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
            ArrayList<String> arrayCountry = new ArrayList<>();            arrayCountry.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_country)));
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    MainActivityRespaldo2.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCountry);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
                    switch (posicion) {
                        case 0 :
                            Intent i0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alemania.class);
                            startActivity(i0);
                            break;
                        case 1 :
                            Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mexico.class);
                            startActivity(i1);
                            break;
                        case 2 :
                            Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EUA.class);
                            startActivity(i2);
                            break;
                        case 3 :
                            Intent i3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Argentina.class);
                            startActivity(i3);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Developing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater  = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar, menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuBuscar);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: When you filter in the listview then the result array position will changed..So can check the country name not the position...please try this.

Comment: Can you make the question clearer ? Because click's index is same with original array index.

Comment: Have you ever tried out getItem in the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of day's ago I was doing the some project and digging on internet but I found the solution yesterday. In my way it may not be professional but it works very fine and help you.The concept is I will identify my products by their corresponding code and whenever any one searches it, the it will get its code and it will open the activity.

My adaptor class.

```
public class MainActivityAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivityAdapter.Holderview>{
    private List<Item> productlist;
    private Context context;
    public MainActivityAdapter(List<Item> productlist, Context context) {
        this.productlist = productlist;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override    public Holderview onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layout= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.customitem,parent,false);
        return new Holderview(layout);
    }
    @Override    public void onBindViewHolder(Holderview holder, final int position) {
        holder.v_name.setText(productlist.get(position).getName());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (productlist.get(position).getCode()=="A")
                {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, one.class));

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Position is"+productlist.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(productlist.get(position).getCode()=="B")
                {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, two.class));
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Position is"+productlist.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(productlist.get(position).getCode()=="C")
                {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, three.class));
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Position is"+productlist.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(productlist.get(position).getCode()=="D")
                {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, four.class));
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Position is"+productlist.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(productlist.get(position).getCode()=="E")
                {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, five.class));
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Position is"+productlist.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
    }
    @Override    public int getItemCount() {
        return productlist.size();
    }
    public void setfilter(List<Item> listitem)
    {
        productlist=new ArrayList<>();
        productlist.addAll(listitem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    class Holderview extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView v_name;
        Holderview(View itemview)
        {
            super(itemview);

            v_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
        }
    }
    public void SetFilter(ArrayList<Item> newList)
    {
        productlist= new ArrayList<>();
        productlist.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

My MainActivity class note I have included my string array in main activity and I have added another array which named as Code it will help me to identify after search.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    RecyclerView showrcy;
    List<Item> productlists = new ArrayList<>();
    MainActivityAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        productlists.add(new Item("MyproductOne", "A"));
        productlists.add(new Item("MyproductTwo", "B"));
        productlists.add(new Item("MyproductThree", "C"));
        productlists.add(new Item("MyproductFour", "D"));

        showrcy = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listshow);
        showrcy.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        showrcy.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        adapter = new MainActivityAdapter(productlists, MainActivity.this);
        showrcy.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchfile, menu);
         MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
              return true;
    }

    private List<Item> filter(List<Item> pl, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        final List<Item> filteredModeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Item model : pl) {
            final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (text.startsWith(query)) {
                filteredModeList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModeList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        newText= newText.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<Item> newList= new ArrayList<>();
        for (Item mylists: productlists)
        {
            String name= mylists.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (name.contains(newText))
                newList.add(mylists);
        }
        adapter.SetFilter(newList);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally My getter and setter class is as Item class it helps me to get and set Code and my product list.

```
public class Item {
    private String name,code;

    public Item(String name,String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```